# Scrapy parse html strings from webpage based on css attribute

Tags: python, css, scrapy, centos6.5

I am trying to pull specific URL's on a webpage based on the CSS attribute. I can pull the first one, but I am having difficulties getting the full URL added, or getting more than 1 URL.

I have tried and run into many issues using joinurl or parse. I keep getting global errors with joinurl.

Is there a more simple way of doing this??

I am using Centos 6.5 & Python 2.7.5

**This code below will provide the first URL, but not the http://www...inline**

```
import scrapy

class PdgaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "pdgavideos"  # Name of the Spider, required value

start_urls = ["http://www.pdga.com/videos/"]

# Entry point for the spiders
def parse(self, response):
    SET_SELECTOR = 'tbody'
    for brickset in response.css(SET_SELECTOR):

        HTML_SELECTOR = 'td.views-field.views-field-title a ::attr(href)'
        yield {
            'http://www.pdga.com': brickset.css(HTML_SELECTOR).extract()[0]
        }
```

**Current Output**

http://www.pdga.com 
/videos/2017-glass-blown-open-fpo-rd-2-pt-2-pierce-fajkus-leatherman-c-allen-sexton-leatherman

**Expected Output**

full list of url's without any breaks

*I do not have enough reputation points to post a couple examples*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get absolute urls from relative links, you can use Scrapy [urljoin()](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?#scrapy.http.Response.urljoin) method and rewrite your code like this:

```
import scrapy

class PdgaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "pdgavideos"
    start_urls = ["http://www.pdga.com/videos/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        for link in response.xpath('//td[2]/a/@href').extract():
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(link), callback=self.parse_page)

        # If page contains link to next page extract link and parse
        next_page = response.xpath('//a[contains(., "next")]/@href').extract_first()
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(next_page), callback=self.parse)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        link = response.xpath('//iframe/@src').extract_first()
        yield{
            'you_tube_link': 'http:' + link.split('?')[0]
        }

# To save links in csv format print in console: scrapy crawl pdgavideos -o links.csv
# http://www.youtube.com/embed/tYBF-BaqVJ8
# http://www.youtube.com/embed/_H0hBBc1Azg
# http://www.youtube.com/embed/HRbKFRCqCos
# http://www.youtube.com/embed/yz3D1sXQkKk
# http://www.youtube.com/embed/W7kuKe2aQ_c
```

Comment: Thank you both Tiny.D and vold for your quick response! This is exactly what I was looking to achieve.

vold: am i able to output the data without the word link or anything else displayed before the results?

Comment: You are welcome. As @Tiny.D already pointed out: Scrapy must return either new Request or Item or dictionary. If you want to simply output string with url in the console you better use `requests` with `bs4` or `lxml` parsers.

Comment: @Thomas I edited my answer to provide more desired output.

Comment: Thank you soooooo much vold. If I could give you more points, then I would =D

Answer (score 1):

Your code return a dictionary, that's why it is break:

```
{'http://www.pdga.com': u'/videos/2017-glass-blown-open-fpo-rd-2-pt-2-pierce-fajkus-leatherman-c-allen-sexton-leatherman'}
```

what you could do is to make the yield this dictionary like this:

```
yield {
    'href_link':'http://www.pdga.com'+brickset.css(HTML_SELECTOR).extract()[0]
}
```

This will give you a new dict with the value is no break href.

```
{'href_link': u'http://www.pdga.com/videos/2017-glass-blown-open-fpo-rd-2-pt-2-pierce-fajkus-leatherman-c-allen-sexton-leatherman'}
```

Note: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, refer to [parse function](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.parse).